# React how to highlight multiple components by using 1 ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently use 2 refs to highlight the searched text in 2 components, but what if i have more than 2 components that i want to highlight the searched text ? is it possible that i can highlight searched text in more than 2 components by just 1 ref? or do i have to do it one by one just like the code below?

```
<script type="text/babel">
class MyApp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            inputValue: "",
            fields: [<Ta />],
   fields1: [<Ta1 />]
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        let object = this.refs.Progress1;
        let fields = this.state.fields;

        let searchBarText = e.target.value;
        let divText = object.textContent;
        let idx = divText.indexOf(searchBarText);
        if (idx >= 0) {
           let newText = [divText.substring(0, idx),
                <strong>{divText.substring(idx, idx + searchBarText.length)}</strong>, divText.substring(idx + searchBarText.length)];
            this.setState({ inputValue: searchBarText, fields: newText });
        } else {
            this.setState({ inputValue: searchBarText, fields: fields });
        }
//second ref
    let object1 = this.refs.Progress2;

        let fields1 = this.state.fields1;

        let searchBarText1 = e.target.value;
        let divText1 = object1.textContent;
        let idx1 = divText1.indexOf(searchBarText1);
        if (idx1 >= 0) {
           let newText1 = [divText1.substring(0, idx1),
                <strong>{divText1.substring(idx1, idx1 + searchBarText1.length)}</strong>, divText1.substring(idx1 + searchBarText1.length)];
            this.setState({ inputValue: searchBarText1, fields1: newText1 });
        } else {
            this.setState({ inputValue: searchBarText1, fields1: fields1 });
        }


    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                className="input"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                placeholder="Search..."
            />
            <p  ref="Progress1" id="try">
                <p>{this.state.fields}</p>
            </p>
  <p  ref="Progress2">
                <p>{this.state.fields1}</p>
            </p>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

class Ta extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <p >this is a dog</p>;
    }
}

class Ta1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <p>this is another dog</p>;
    }
}




ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app2"));

</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an array? You're using them already, just use an array of arrays

Comment: you mean something like  fields: [<Ta />, <Ta1 /> ,<Ta2 />]?

Comment: Yeah... why not?

Comment: i try it already, it only works for the first one <Ta />.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array of arrays as suggested by @FrankerZ. Here's how I would implement it:

The component state:

```
this.state = {
    inputValue: "",
    fields: [[<Ta />], [<Ta1 />]]
};
```

handleChange method:

```
handleChange(e) {
    for(let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        let refString = "Progress" + i; // pick the suitable ref, Progress1, Progress2, etc...
        let object = this.refs[refString];
        let fields = this.state.fields;

        let searchBarText = e.target.value;
        let divText = object.textContent;
        let idx = divText.indexOf(searchBarText);
        if (idx >= 0) {
            let newText = [divText.substring(0, idx),
                <strong>{divText.substring(idx, idx + searchBarText.length)}</strong>, divText.substring(idx + searchBarText.length)];
            fields[i-1] = newText; // set the new value to the suitable array in the array of arrays
            this.setState({ inputValue: searchBarText, fields: fields });
        } else {
            this.setState({ inputValue: searchBarText, fields: fields });
        }
    }
}
```

In the render method make each element correspond to the suitable array in the array of arrays:

```
render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            className="input"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder="Search..."
        />
        <p  ref="Progress1" id="try">
            <p>{this.state.fields[0]}</p>
        </p>
<p  ref="Progress2">
            <p>{this.state.fields[1]}</p>
        </p>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Now if you want to add a new element to have its text searched, add it and make its `ref` be `Progress3` and add it to the array of arrays in the state.

Comment: Thank you again ^_^